# Sum of table attributes when value is string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I've never came across this before. I'm working with a table attribute whos value is a string, not float/int.

```
Model.first.amount => "58.00"
```

I need to sum up all amount. What I'm used to, with the `amount` being a float, would be:

```
Model.all.sum(&:amount) => # total value
```

Took a wild guess with:

```
Model.all.sum(&:amount.to_i) # undefined method `to_i' for :amount:Symbol
```

Is there a clean way to sum up the amount? Or convert the database to `float`?

Comment: You need to do casting as SELECT CAST('1234' AS FLOAT).

Comment: You shouldn't use floats for monetary amounts.

Comment: I know. I'm working with someone's db. They wont listen on changing it.

Comment: No, I mean: you should not convert the string values to float. Use a type that can handle exact storage like `BigDecimal` in Ruby or `DECIMAL` in SQL.

Comment: Ahhh! Thanks for that. Such as `amount.to_d`?

Comment: You don't use `Model.all.sum(&:amount)` unless you want to force ActiveRecord to load all the records and then sum everything in memory in Ruby. The ampersand is a special syntax shortcut in ruby for passing methods as arguments and will force the use of Enumerable#sum!  Its `Model.all.sum(:amount)` which will create a `SELECT SUM("models"."amount") FROM "models"` query.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Processing database with Ruby is memory inefficient.

First shot:

```
Model
  .pluck(:amount) # will fire sql
  .sum(&:to_f)    # convert to float, operating on resulting Array, not AR and sum
```

But the most effective way to process database data is SQL of course:

```
Model.sum("CAST(COALESCE(amount, '0') AS DECIMAL)")
```

1. `coalesce` will replace null values with `'0'`
2. `sum` all values casted to `DECIMAL`.

Comment: IIRC, you have to specify the precision, e.g. `DECIMAL(10,2)`

Comment: @Stefan AFAIR specifying precision is optional

Answer (score 1):

In pure Ruby you can use method `inject`.

```
Model.all.inject(0) { |sum, object| sum += object.amount.to_i }
```

Comment: bad idea, if there's a lot of objects this approach will lead to memory overload.

Comment: And the data is decimal (or float storage done by idiots) - not integers.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have commenting permissions but this should work for ruby:

```
Model.all.map(&:to_f).reduce(&:+)
```

Comment: This will not work, because you have to sum the values of amount attributes and not the objects themselves. `Model.all.map(&:amount).map(&:to_f).reduce(&:+)`